# Oracle Missing keyword using case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, case-when, merge-statement

I have below stored procedure for which i am getting an error as missing keyword. I am trying to run the sql statement by putting them into variable  because i have use the database link dynamically in the sql query. I am getting the error while using `case statement` in merge query. When i am using dbms output line to print the merge query then its printing the complete case statement instead of only ID.

```
    PROCEDURE                    "EXT_SOAP_MONITORING"(IN_DB_LINK IN varchar2) AS

    LAST_SM_ID Number := 0;
    LAST_CAPT_DATE DATE;
    LAST_SM_ID_MB Number := 0;
    LAST_CAPT_DATE_MB DATE;
    l_sql VARCHAR2(5000);
    l_sql1 VARCHAR2(5000);
    DB_CONNECTION_NAME VARCHAR2(100);

    BEGIN

    Select DB_LINK INTO DB_CONNECTION_NAME FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.DB_CONNECTION WHERE DB_LINK = IN_DB_LINK;
    --DELETE FROM TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING table before inserting new data into this table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

    -- first retrieve the last id (of the newest record) which has been imported at last extraction
    --FONIC
    SELECT LAST_TASK_ID INTO LAST_SM_ID FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING' and DB ='FONIC_RETAIL';
    SELECT CAPTURING_DATE INTO LAST_CAPT_DATE from CAPTURING WHERE DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING' and DB ='FONIC_RETAIL';

    --MB
    SELECT LAST_TASK_ID INTO LAST_SM_ID_MB FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING' and DB ='MB_RETAIL';
    SELECT CAPTURING_DATE INTO LAST_CAPT_DATE_MB from CAPTURING WHERE DB_TABLE='TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING' and DB ='MB_RETAIL';

    l_sql:=
'merge into TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING TSM
using (
   select * from
(select ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE from
SOAP_MONITORING@'||DB_CONNECTION_NAME||'  WHERE 
ID > (CASE WHEN '||IN_DB_LINK||' = ''FONIC_RETAIL'' THEN ' || LAST_SM_ID || ' ELSE ' || LAST_SM_ID_MB ||' END) AND
WEB_SERVICE_NAME =''RatorWebShopService''  and WEB_METHOD_NAME = ''placeShopOrder'') where rownum <=1000
) data
ON (TSM.ID = data.ID)
when not matched then
insert(ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE,DB_LINK)
values(data.ID,data.REQUEST_XML,data.RESPONSE_XML,data.WEB_SERVICE_NAME,data.WEB_METHOD_NAME,data.CREATE_DATE,data.ERROR_CODE,data.ERROR_MESSAGE,'||DB_CONNECTION_NAME ||')';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lsql' || l_sql);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lsql' || l_sql);

    execute immediate l_sql;

    END EXT_SOAP_MONITORING;
```

Below is my DBMS result:

```
     merge into TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING TSM
using (
   select * from
(select ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE from
SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL  WHERE 
ID > (CASE WHEN FONIC_RETAIL = 'FONIC_RETAIL' THEN 201601071130573261 ELSE 201601071130573261 END) AND
WEB_SERVICE_NAME ='RatorWebShopService'  and WEB_METHOD_NAME = 'placeShopOrder') where rownum <=1000
) data
ON (TSM.ID = data.ID)
when not matched then
insert(ID,REQUEST_XML,RESPONSE_XML,WEB_SERVICE_NAME,WEB_METHOD_NAME,CREATE_DATE,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE,DB_LINK)
values(data.ID,data.REQUEST_XML,data.RESPONSE_XML,data.WEB_SERVICE_NAME,data.WEB_METHOD_NAME,data.CREATE_DATE,data.ERROR_CODE,data.ERROR_MESSAGE,FONIC_RETAIL)
```

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: i guess you are missing a whitespace after the `THEN'`

Comment: i have corrected that now its showing ID but still i am getting the same error. Its printing the complete case statement in merge query. I just want to take ID from that case expression

Comment: @Rahul As an aside, why are you using two sql statements to get two columns from the same row? You know you can do `select col1, col2, ... into v1, v2, ...` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the missing whitespace after the `THEN` that @KevinEsche pointed out, you're also missing an AND (or OR) after the case statement:

```
<snip>
    || ' END)
WEB_SERVICE_NAME =''RatorWebShopService'' <snip> -- <---- missing and/or before web_service_name
```

---

So, looking at the merge statement which was output by your procedure, there are two issues that leap out, coincidentally on the same line:

```
ID > (CASE WHEN DB_LINK = 'FONIC_RETAIL' THEN201601071130573261 ELSE  END) AND
```

You forgot to add in the space after the `THEN` in `THEN' || LAST_SM_ID`, plus you haven't catered for `LAST_SM_ID_MB` being null.

---

Here's how I'd write the procedure

```
procedure ext_soap_monitoring (in_db_link in varchar2)
as
  last_sm_id number := 0;
  last_capt_date date;
  last_sm_id_mb number := 0;
  last_capt_date_mb date;
  l_sql varchar2(5000);
  l_sql1 varchar2(5000);
  db_connection_name varchar2(100);

begin
  select db_link
  into   db_connection_name
  from   rator_monitoring_configuration.db_connection
  where  db_link = in_db_link;

  --DELETE FROM TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING table before inserting new data into this table
  execute immediate 'TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING';

  -- first retrieve the last id (of the newest record) which has been imported at last extraction
  --FONIC
  select last_task_id, capturing_date
  into   last_sm_id, last_capt_date
  from   capturing
  where  db_table = 'TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING'
  and    db = 'FONIC_RETAIL';

  --MB
  select last_task_id, capturing_date
  into   last_sm_id_mb, last_capt_date_mb
  from   capturing
  where  db_table = 'TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING'
  and    db = 'MB_RETAIL';

  l_sql:=
'merge into temp_soap_monitoring tsm
using (select *
       from   (select id,
                      request_xml,
                      response_xml,
                      web_service_name,
                      web_method_name,
                      create_date,
                      error_code,
                      error_message
               from   soap_monitoring@'||db_connection_name||'
               where  id > (case when :db_connection_name = ''FONIC_RETAIL'' then ' || last_sm_id || ' else ' || last_sm_id_mb ||' end)
               and    web_service_name = ''RatorWebShopService''
               and    web_method_name = ''placeShopOrder'')
       where rownum <= 1000) data
on (tsm.id = data.id)
when not matched then
insert (id,
        request_xml,
        response_xml,
        web_service_name,
        web_method_name,
        create_date,
        error_code,
        error_message,
        db_link)
values (data.id,
        data.request_xml,
        data.response_xml,
        data.web_service_name,
        data.web_method_name,
        data.create_date,
        data.error_code,
        data.error_message,
        :db_connection_name)';

  dbms_output.put_line('lsql' || l_sql);

  execute immediate l_sql using db_connection_name, db_connection_name;

end ext_soap_monitoring;
/
```

Note the use of the bind variables to remove the literal placements of the variables in the sql itself. I know you can't avoid using dynamic sql to add in the database link name when you're selecting from the table, but you can use bind variables elsewhere, and this should make your code less prone to sql injection.

Also, see how I've formatted the merge statement - yes, it takes up more room in the variable, but it is one heck of a lot more readable now!

Comment: Hi Bonist i have edited my question and added the DBMS result and as you said its correct that i am missing AND or (OR) after the case statement and i have corrected that but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: You can see its printing the case expression in merge query

Comment: ok i will add the the condition to check the null condition also

Comment: Hello Boniest i have updated my DBMS result in question. Now the previous error is not there but now i am getting the error as "TSM"."DB_LINK": invalid identifier. I have column DB_LINK in TEMP_SOAP_MONITORING table but still i am getting this error.

Comment: In case statement i just want to check if the db link(its coming from input parameter) which is saved in variable DB_CONNECTION_NAME is fonic_retail then take LAST_SM_ID else take LAST_SM_ID_MB

Comment: @Rahul the issue you're now getting is because you've referenced `tsm.db_link` inside your source query (which you've aliased as `data`) but you haven't given an alias to the `soap_monitoring@fonic_retail` table. If you're actually wanting to reference the column in the `temp_soap_monitoring` table, you need to join it into your source query. You cannot directly reference the table you're trying to merge into in the source query.

Comment: Ohh i see i made a mistake in my query while assigning TSM.DB_LINK which is not correct. I have to check that if the DB_CONNECTION_NAME value is fonic_retail then take LAST_SM_ID else take LAST_SM_ID_MB but really not understanding how to do that. You can see the value in the DB_CONNECTION_NAME is coming from parameter IN_DB_LINK.

Comment: @Boniest is it possible to check in my case statement if the db_connection_name is fonic_retail then take LAST_SM_ID else take LAST_SM_ID_MB ?

Comment: you want to check the value of the `IN_DB_LINK` parameter in the case statement? If so, just use `IN_DB_LINK` in the case statement... e.g. `case when in_db_link = 'FONIC_RETAIL' then ...`

Comment: I tried that before and also updated the dbms result in question just now but getting error as "FONIC_RETAIL": invalid identifier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100054/discussion-between-rahul-and-boneist).

Comment: I can't, I'm afraid; firewall *{:-( The latest issue you're getting is because the last thing you're inserting is `FONIC_RETAIL`, but it should probably be in single-quotes, i.e. `'FONIC_RETAIL'`

Comment: but its the variable value i am assigning there not hardcoded so can i do that ? I am making a very small mistake but unable to identify :(. I have updated my code in question can u plz tell me in code change where i have to make. I have tried various possibilities but still getting issue.

Comment: You already know how to put single quotes inside a string; I know, because I can see you've already done it! You need to do the same thing but around where you're assigning the parameter: `values (<snip>,'||DB_CONNECTION_NAME ||')';`

Comment: Great! I've also updated my answer with how I'd write that procedure, fwiw.

Comment: Hello boniest i am sorry but i am still getting the error now when i have updated your answer. The error is ORA-01008: not all variables bound.

Comment: how many bind variables have you declared in your dynamic sql, and how many variables did you pass in to the execute immediate?